# Beginner query related to java web apps

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I am creating a web app using java. I am very new to this, and I have the following questions:

1. I have `jsp` files for the front-end. Now, whenever I have to do a bulky back-end function I can either create a servlet and do a get request from jsp or I can create a simple java object, instantiate it in jsp and use it for backed function.
   Which one is better and why?
2. Each back-end function needs to connect to a database. I want to do it only once for a user for the entire session and for all `jsp` pages. How is it done?

Comment: I am not sure if anyone can give a clear anwer to this question. Both points are more a software architectural question than a programming problem, and every architecture has it pros and cons. "Connect to a database" also depends on what database you are using, usually the appication connects once to a database, not the user itself. I would suggest to write some example applications to find out which way you think is the best. When you have more specific questions, we are better able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1:

If no servlet is needed why use it? Just do your bulky work in a plain Java class. By this way you will have less dependencies in you workflow.

For question 2:

Most app servers now have build in support for pooled connections. It is strongly adviced that you make use of this functionality. Now, there are plenty of ways you can go forward. The simplest and IMO best way is to create a database related Object that will handle connection open/close, perform updates/delete/select functions, and make use of this through out your application

Answer (score 2):

1. Neither of those two. Read about the MVC pattern. Make every request coming from the browser go to a servlet. Make this servlet call services of the backend and populate Java Beans stored in a request attribute. Then dispatch the request to a JSP. The JSP's only responsibility should be to get the data from the beans in the request and generate the HTML markup of the page (with the help of the JSTL and custom tags. No scriptlet).
2. A database connection should not be reserved to a single user. If you have 1000 concurrent users doing one request every 30 seconds, you would need 1000 connections, staying idle most of the time. This is more than the database can support, and these connections could timeout orfail anyway. Read about connection pools, and use one: each request needing a connection gets one from the pool, does its job, and then closes the connection, which in fact gives it back to the pool where it comes from, ready to serve another request.

Comment: sry for the term database connection,I am actually connecting to a webservice using user credentials.so I need to do it once for every user

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you opt for a framework, such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) (you can find a list of tutorials [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662857/java-spring-tutorials)) you will end up with cleaner JSP files and a more structured project. Spring should also stop you from re-inventing the wheel and start everything from scratch.

With regards to your second question, I do not understand your question. If you want to open one connection per user then you are going to consume resources which could be used for other more useful things. Such a system will also *not* scale up. For this I would recommend another framework, [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) which you could use in your *Data Access Layer* (read more about the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) to manage database transactions.